# Eclipse Glassfish launch configuration - VM arguments are ignored

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, glassfish-4, eclipse-kepler

I am struggling to set up Glassfish 4 with Eclipse Kepler. No matter what I do, the VM arguments of the Glassfish launch configuration are not passed on to the VM running the server. Not even the argument (-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009) that is put into the launch configuration by default by the Glassfish Tools for Eclipse plugin.

The running server has all system properties set according to the `domain.xml` of the started domain. The VM arguments specified in the start configuration are all lost on the way.

I have updated the Glassfhish plugin to the latest version. I have downloaded and unzipped Glassfish and then told Eclipse where to find the runtime. I have also let Eclipse download and install the server through the add-new-runtime wizard. It makes no difference.

The VM arguments text box contents are used though. If I enter two dashes I get an error, as expected, telling me that two dashes are not a valid VM option.

I was not able to find anything along the lines of this problem on the web. Which gives me the feeling that I am going about this the wrong way. But how?

The launch configuration:
[image: Launch configuration]

VisualVM and `ps -e | grep glassfish` show none of the VM arguments.

Comment: Are you using a Mac?  The comments on this bug https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS-343 indicates that maybe it's still broken for Mac users.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 and it is broken also. Although the VM arguments are read when running Glassfish in Debug mode.

Comment: @Gus Yes, I am running Eclipse on OSX.

Comment: This seems to work in Eclipse Luna on Windows 7. I can try it on Ubuntu tomorrow but I don't have a OSX system. Are you still using Eclipse Kepler?

Comment: @unwichtich Yes, I am still on Kepler SR2.

Comment: You should use "ps -ef", also try "jps -vlm", and finally change the suspend arg to "suspend=y", and the glassfish must wait until debugger is attached, if it doesn't then the jvm args are really ignored for some reason. Btw if you just want to run glassfish in debug mode, you don't have to pass agentlib args yourself, you can run it in debug mode directly from Eclipse.

Comment: @stackdev `jps` does not show the specified VM arguments either. I don't want to just debug the application. The application needs the location of a properties file to start. I had to specify all VM args as `<jvm-options>` entries in the domain.xml because they are not picked up from the launch configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm wrong, but i think the eclipse plugin internally calls `asadmin` to start glassfish.

So VM arguments are not ignored, are used only on asadmin VM instance.

This may be plausible

1. eclipse plugin calls `asadmin start-domain domain1`: batch file is launched.
2. `asadmin` calls `java -arguments-from-eclipse-plugin ...`, let's name it `java(asadmin)`. A first VM instance is created in which run asadmin classes, not glassfish.
3. `java(asadmin)` calls `java -arguments-from-domain-xml ...` to start glassfish, let's name it `java(glassfish)`.
4. when the second VM instance is running, `java(asadmin)` exits.

So `java(asadmin)` does not transfer its arguments to `java(glassfish)`.

I have no direct evidence of this behavior, but stated that:

1. eclipse plugin arguments are lost
2. domain.xml arguments are retained

this could be the reason.

Comment: VM arguments are retained when in DEBUG mode though.

Comment: maybe eclipse plugin uses a different launch mode (without asadmin) when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Are settings maybe ignored due to an (unsolicited) existence of parameters both in domain.xml and Eclipse?

Would this post help?
[Glassfish 4.0 won't start from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634750/glassfish-4-0-wont-start-from-eclipse)

Or this (seem also to affect 4.0):
https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-6582

https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-install-guide/v56/setting-jvm-options-application-servers#additional_646152231_1160916

Can't you just ditch the plugin/use another application server? Used JBoss AS and it was ok...

Comment: Nope, the application specific parameters certainly were not present in the stock domain.xml. It also does not work with Glassfish 3 either. Glassfish is set as the server runtime. No change possible here.

Comment: Really does sound annoying! Best luck ;)