# Where to put "Java options"

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I am having a problem connecting to a SSL host, I am getting an error:

```
Severe: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
```

I think that I found an answer here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8065184

I think that my solution might be the answer:

```
The issue has been resolved by setting the following two JAVA options:
-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

Where should I put these "Java options"? Is there any way to put these options in with Java? I am using Eclipse and Glassfish.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You have to add these Java options when starting Glassfish. See the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056809/eclipse-glassfish-launch-configuration-vm-arguments-are-ignored for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Run -> Run Configurations...** menu, in the lookup menu on the left type *Glassfish* and select your launch configuration. In the **Argument** tab you will find a **VM Arguments** box - add your Java options there.